# I want Find finite dimensional densities for an $\mathbb R^d-$ valued Gaussian process $X$with specified mean and covariance functions

Tags: probability, self-study, stochastic-processes, gaussian-process

Write the finite dimensional densities for an $\mathbb R^d-$ valued Gaussian process $X$with specified mean and covariance functions.

Comment: First: edit your title, because **everyone** here want to solve some problems. Second: your description is a little bit vague, did you consider writing something more? Do you have any thoughts how the problem could be solved? And finally: add an `self-study` tag because this seems to be a self-study kind of question.

Comment: Since formulas for the multivariate Gaussian density in terms of means the covariances are well known (and simple), please tell us more specifically where you need assistance in applying those formulas.